# using Drupal Aggregator module, trying to export OPML

Tags: 7

using Drupal 7, trying the aggregator module. It looked promising, so imported my OPML file from Google Reader to it a while back.  But Aggregator has too many bugs to keep using it. It seems to corrupt the db when deleting or editing items, and it hangs up in the cron job for updates when items are bad, with no good way to find them and fix or remove them. Also, can't do a view of items in a category; that simply does not work (or only works for the primary category set by the feed itself - can't use a category that is set on individual items later).  The block for the category works but you can't get a feed from the block.

so, trying to get my feeds back out of drupal;  but apparently there is no way to export it as OPML...  one way street. a real pain.

does anyone know how to export the aggregator data (preferably as OPML) so I can try using some other service, like The Old Reader.